# convert XML to PDF Suitelet without making advance PDF tempelate

Tags: javascript, pdf, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I created button to download XML (excel) `ExcelStr` and downloaded fine

```
 ExcelStr += '</Table></Worksheet></Workbook>';


               
                var strXmlEncoded = encode.convert({
                    string: ExcelStr,
                    inputEncoding: encode.Encoding.UTF_8,
                    outputEncoding: encode.Encoding.BASE_64
                });

                var objXlsFile = file.create({
                    name: 'Report Summary Item Receipt' + ' from ' + start + ' to ' + end + '.xls',
                    fileType: file.Type.EXCEL,
                    contents: strXmlEncoded

                });

                context.response.writeFile({
                    file: objXlsFile
                });
```

and i want to make an button to download the pdf version. how do i convert my xml file into pdf withourt having to create and import data into advenced pdf tempelate?